# Missing Double Array

Tags: java

I am having a problem with my output.  When I run the program I am getting an array that prints out zeros. Some of these variables are supposed to be in between 0 and 1. But I am getting all of the variables as zero. I also have a another problem with the program but I am not sure if I should ask two questions on the same post and where to go tag this question.(It is about the math of the equation.)
The output is supposed to look like: [this](http://prntscr.com/2eydse)
Recap I my question is why my double array is being printed out as zero.
Input is :

- 3700465.457603474
- 8866199.9605471
- 9794740.68167652
- 3697967.6848667157
- 2.4776754466506414E7
- 1.043814587026926E7
- 8861473.215210252
- 1.1131680688084042E7
- 612807.1987535232

---

```
public class Weight1 {

    public static double[]  gravity (double[] z) throws IOException
    {
        File fileName= new File("gravity.txt");
        Scanner inFile= new Scanner(fileName);
        for( int i=0; i<z.length; i++)
        {
        z[i]= inFile.nextDouble();
    }
        return z;
  }

  public static double [] realgravity (double []z, double[] o) {
     for ( int bo=0; bo<z.length; bo++)
     {
         o[bo]= z[bo]*6.67E-11;
        }
     return o;
    }

  public static double[] realweight(double[] calcWeight, double earthWeight,double[] o)
    {
       for ( int bit=0; bit<calcWeight.length;bit++)
       {
           calcWeight[bit]= earthWeight/o[bit];
        }
        return calcWeight;
    } 
  public static void printResults(String[] names, double [] o, double[] calcWeight) throws IOException
  {
      System.out.println(" My weight on planets:");
      System.out.println(" Planet     Gravity     Weight(lbs)");
      System.out.println("=====================================");
      for (int iq=0; iq<o.length; iq++)
      {
          System.out.printf( "%1s " , names[iq]);
          System.out.printf( "%8.2f", o[iq]);
          System.out.printf("%17.1f",calcWeight[iq]);
          System.out.printf("%n");
        }

    }


 // Note: formula for finding weight on a planet:  Earth weight divided by Gravity constant times surface gravity

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {


    double earthWeight = 100.0; // initalize Earth weight to 100 lbs
    double [] z= new double [9];
    double [] o= new double [9];
    double [] calcWeight= new double [9];
    String printResults;
    double coin[]= gravity(z);
    double bit[]= realgravity(z,o);
    double next[]=realweight(calcWeight,earthWeight,o);


    String[] names = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune","Pluto"};


    printResults(names,o,calcWeight);
     // static method you write
              // static method you write

}
```

Comment: Well, did you try stepping through your code in the debugger?  That is step #1.

Comment: Unrelated, but the code is a little confusing, what with passing in arrays you're returning and all.

Comment: What is the purpose of `String printResults`? It doesn't seem to be used anywhere in your code.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yes, I don't get any errors from my debugger, I'm pretty sure it might be the arrangement of the program or the math of the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your gravity values (in the "o" array) are very small numbers:

```
[0] 2.4682104602215173E-4   
[1] 5.913755373684916E-4    
[2] 6.533092034678239E-4    
[3] 2.466544445806099E-4    
[4] 0.0016526095229159779
```

You then print them out with a format specifier of :

```
  System.out.printf( "%8.2f", o[iq]);
```

which rounds all the values to two decimal places; hence, the 0.00 values.  So you have an error in your calculations.  Correction of that is left to you to try,  Recommendation - learn how to use your IDE's debugger.  Is it the developer's most important tool.  I found this error literally in two minutes with the debugger, and stepping through the code.